# Error by using res.sendfile() in nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, socket.io

i m having project on nodejs, im begginer in nodejs.
when i try to use this

`app.get('/', function(req, res) res.sendfile('index.html');});`

its tells me to use **sendFile**( calital **F**).
And When I use capital F in sendFile, its shows me this error

```
TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile
```

at ServerResponse.sendFile

What should I do anybode help me

Comment: `npm` comes bundled with node.js. How do you have `npm` installed without having node.js installed?

Comment: yes i have installed npm and nodejs as wel

Comment: Then why are you trying to run `npm install nodejs`?

Comment: Your output seems to be for running `npm install nodejs`. What's the output when running `npm install express`?

Comment: now, i m okay! but having this problem

Answer (score 1):

Can you try running as sudo ?

sudo npm install nodejs

better way to install node is to download the installers
https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Answer (score 0):

You should enter the exact filepath of the file in your system.

Add this to the top of the file:

```
var path = require('path');
```

Then:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){ 
    console.log(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html')); //See the output in console
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html')); //this joins your current directory and filename, giving you the full path to the file.
});
```

I don't know why it's not working for you. Just writing 'index.html' usually works. But this will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me!

```
        var path = require('path');
        res.sendFile(path.resolve('output.xlsx'));
```

Bye!

Answer (score 0):

if you have `'home/../public/index.html'` these kind of paths then
you've to use

```
const path = require('path');
.
.
.

app.get('/', async(req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname+'/../public/index.html'));
})
```